# Span value updating only once in SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 and SignalR 1.1.4 to make a live notification where a value inside a span will update every time a user from other side send a message. The problem is it'll update the value only the first time, no matter how many times I send the message. Here are my codes,

**Hub Code**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Adminreply()
    {
        Clients.All.adminNewReplyToPage();
    }
}
```

**JS Code**

```
$(function () {
    var chat3 = $.connection.chatHub;
    var usernotifyVal = parseInt($('.badge').html(), 10);    // '.badge' is span's class
    var usernewVal = usernotifyVal + 1;

    chat3.client.adminNewReplyToPage = function () {
        $('.badge').empty().append(usernewVal);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#admin_btnReply').click(function () {
            chat3.server.adminreply();
        });
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong with my code? How can I update the span value every time user sends a message in live?

Comment: any error in console ?? can you put `console.log` in `adminNewReplyToPage` to check the output ?

Comment: I checked as you mentioned, but found no error in console.

Comment: did you check the second thing i mentioned ? @Sin

Comment: Yes, I get the value of updated `usernewVal`, but not updating in span after first time.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, correction, `usernewVal` is not updating after first time.

Comment: where did you update  `usernewVal` when message is post from another client ?

Comment: It's ok now, I solved it. just replaced `usernewVal++` and worked for me. Thank you for your time!